# Fast lookup does not always return data as expected - sometimes will after wait

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm running into an issue with some of my flows where a Fast Lookup will not return any records, when I know for a fact there are items that meet the criteria.

I added a Wait statement to my flow, and after a few minutes it routes back to the lookup - often on the second try, it will succeed. (I added a counter variable so I only retry 3 times and then bail.) Nothing has changed in the underlying data - the records were always there - they just were not found the first time.
Has anyone else experienced this?

Here is a log snippet which illustrates the problem.  You'll see that the first lookup fails ("Failed to find records"), then a wait of one minute, then a success.

Thanks for any thoughts / suggestions.

FAST LOOKUP: Get_Opportunity
Find all Opportunity records where:
Custom_field__c Equals true
AccountId Equals {!oli.AccountId} (00139000006Hm3tAAC)
Assign those records to {!CurrentOpp}.
Save these field values in the variable: Id
Result
**Failed to find records.**

Event Type: Alarm: Absolute Time
Base Time = {!Flow.CurrentDateTime} (4/26/2016 3:23 PM)
Offset Unit = Hours
Offset Number = 0
Result
Started waiting at 4/26/2016 3:23 PM.

The interview started waiting at 4/26/2016 3:23 PM.
The interview was resumed at 4/26/2016 3:26 PM by Robb Allen (00429000000fq8t).

WAIT: Wait_for_1_minute
Wait event Wait_for_1_minute_and_try_again occurred.
The following values from the event were assigned to flow variables.
{!Waittime} () = AlarmTime (4/26/2016 3:23 PM)

FAST LOOKUP: Get_Opportunity
Find all Opportunity records where:
Custom_field__c Equals true
AccountId Equals {!oli.AccountId} (00139000006Hm3tAAC)
Assign those records to {!CurrentOpp}.
Save these field values in the variable: Id
Result
**Successfully found records.**